# Graphics Co-ordinates Problems

Tags: .net, graphics, coordinates

We have some legacy hardware/software that displays graphics through a Matrox card out to a TV. The graphics are composites of files (bmp, tga) and text elements. The layout of the graphics is in an XML file. I am trying to render these graphics in a window for previewing without access to the special hardware. I'm using basic .NET gfx classes: Bitmap and Graphics.

The problem is I can't get the co-ordinates in the XML file to match where the objects should be displayed in the window. For example, the XML says render "test.bmp" at 13,159 but in the example graphic it should be at 94, 24. Another is XML co-ord is 232,-48 but real co-ord is 530, 138.

I know that's not a lot of info to go on but if anyone has any input on how to map these co-ordinates I'd appreciate it. The full graphic size is 720x486.

To composite the images I do:

```
// Target bitmap all others get composited into
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(720, 486);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
// Load a new bitmap
string file_name;         // Path to image from XML file
float x, y;               // Position. Pulled from the XML
float w, h;               // Width and height. Also from the XML. Seems always to be Bitmap w,h
float scale_x, scale_y;   // Scaling. Also from the XML
// Parse XML file....
Bitmap bmp_new = new Bitmap(file_name);
RectangleF r = new RectangleF(x, y, w * scale_x, h * scale_y);
g.DrawImage(bmp_new, r);
pixPreview.Image = bmp;    // PictureBox control for veiwing
```

Comment: Where the bitmap will end up is determined by the pixPreview's SizeMode property.